# How to "freeze" just part of an array or string?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to "freeze" just the nth character of a string or the nth index of an array. So when I make a change, it won't change the selected index.
Something like ".freeze[i]"

- Example, "freezing" the first character or first index.
- Rotate method is also just an example. It could be any modification to the array as soon it does not modify the place and value of the selected index.

  ```
  arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].rotate
  # If we want index 0 to be "frozen":
  ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b']
  ```

  or

  ```
  str = 'abcde'.rotate
  # If we want range index 0..2 to be "frozen":
  'abced'
  ```

Any ideas on how to do it, will be very much appreciated!

Ps.
I know freeze method has nothing to do with what I'm trying to achieve (freeze here is a word and not a method). 
Although it is the best I could do to make it easy to understand and easy to be found by others throughout the community.

Thanks all for helping and making this a great community!
I'll promise to do my best and help everyone back! :)

Comment: What you are trying to do has nothing to do with freezing. Don't use terminology that you don't understand.

Comment: What you are trying to do is actually impossible and does not make any sense. How can a method (your `freeze[0]` or `freeze[0..2]`) know the state of the object before the previous operation `rotate` had applied?

Comment: I didn't answer your question. I don't know what you are mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because a string is frozen doesn't mean it can't be moved somewhere else in an array. Freezing an object just prevents the object itself from being modified.

What I would do is take out the element that you don't want to move, rotate the array, then put it back in at the same index after the rotation, like this:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
index = 0
item = arr.delete_at(index)
arr.rotate!
arr.insert(index, item)
```

After that arr will be `["a", "c", "d", "e", "b"]`

Comment: Hi, Addison! I like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't freeze a portion of a string. Likewise, you can't freeze specific indexes of an array. You can freeze the value of a specific item in an array, as an array is essentially a collection of values.

```
array = []
array[] << "value".freeze
array[0] # is frozen
```

However, you are freezing the value at position 0 in the array, not the position itself.

Comment: Thanks, Simone. Nice to know that I can't do that to the position itself!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that will work for what you are trying to do. You are not freezing the indexes in Ruby terms, but this method will hold the objects place.

```
def freeze_index(term, array)
original_array = array
if term.is_a?(Fixnum)
    frozen_terms = array[term]
    #Delete all the 'frozen' terms
    original_array.delete_at(term)
    original_array.rotate!
    # insert the 'frozen' terms back into their original spots
    original_array = original_array.insert(term, frozen_terms)
elsif term.is_a?(Range)
    # convert the range into an array to make pulling the integers out of it easier
    term_array = term.to_a
    n = 0

    frozen_terms = []

    #put the frozen terms into an array
    term.each {|index| frozen_terms << array[index]}

    #make the frozen terms equal to nil
    term_array.each { |index| original_array[index] = nil}
    #get rid of the nils and rotate the remaining terms
    original_array.compact!.rotate!

    # go through all the frozen terms and insert them back into their original places
    frozen_terms.each do |item|
        original_array = original_array.insert(term_array[n], item )
        n += 1
    end
    original_array
end
end


a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
freeze_index((0..2), a)
```

This will return ["a", "b", "c", "e", "d"]

Comment: Wow! A whole method about it. Thanks, JonahR that's really cool!